# instantiate sound clips dynamically in as3

Tags: audio, actionscript-3

How can i call and instantiate soundclips in my library dynamically

here is the code i have so far

```
function soundbutton_Handler (e:MouseEvent):void {
trace(e.target.name);
var mySound:Sound = new e.target();

mySound.play();
}
```

and the error i get is :
Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
 at quiz_fla::MainTimeline/soundbutton_Handler()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, for future reference if any one needs help i 'm posting the solution here

```
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(e.target.name) as Class;
var mysound:Sound = new classRef();
mysound.play();
```